# ACF Block - Serialize data

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to save data into ACF blocks via wp_insert_post() function.

My example data is a table, where ‘main_text’ might include new lines, single or double quotes, html tags like links.

I have a function to generate an ACF block and insert to $postData[‘post_content’].
However, my code doesn’t create new lines on the block.

```
$postData = array(
 'post_type' => 'reports',
 'post_status' => 'draft',
 'post_title' => 'Post Title';
);
$postData['post_content'] = getPostContent();
$postID = wp_insert_post($postData);

function getPostContent() {
    $dataToSave = [
      'mode' => 'edit',
      'name' => 'acf/pd-text',
      'data' => [
        'title' => 'Example Block Title',
        'main_text' => 'This is the first line
This is the line
[custom-shortcode id="5" caption="Title"]
Another line with link <a href="">Link text</a>.'
      ]
    ];

    $attrs = wp_json_encode( $dataToSave, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
    $attrs = addslashes( $attrs );

    return '<!-- wp:' . $name . ' ' . $attrs . ' /-->';
}
```

My ACF generated code (preview in the Admin Panel - Code editor):

```
<!-- wp:acf/pd-text {"name":"acf/pd-text","data":{"title":"Example Block Title","main_text":"This is the first line\nThis is the line\n[custom-shortcode id=\u00225\u0022 caption=\u0022Title\u0022]\nAnother line with link \u003ca href=\u0022\u0022\u003eLink text\u003c/a\u003e."},"mode":"edit"} /-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:
function setAcfGetBlock(
    string $block,
    array $fieldData
  ) {

    $fields = [];
    foreach($fieldData as $fieldKey => $fieldValue) {
      $key = 'block_' . $block . '_' . $fieldKey;
      $fields[$key] = $fieldValue;
      $fields['_'.$key] = 'field_' . md5($key);
    }

    $json = [
      'name' => 'acf/' . $block,
      'data' => $fields,
      'mode' => 'edit'
    ];

    $fields = json_encode($json);
    $acfJson = <<<ACFJSON
<!-- wp:acf/$block $fields /-->
ACFJSON;

    return $acfJson;
  }
so you can then do something like

wp_insert_post( [
        'post_type' => 'job',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_title' => 'My Jobname',
        'post_content' => setAcfGetBlock('title', [
          'subtitle' => 'My subtitle'
        ])
      ] );
```

Comment: It seems that it does not resolve the problem, I think the problem is how ACF reading generated JSON file. Seems like added \n between new lines not adding on the front. Generated code: https://prnt.sc/U2c2lc6tbLTA you can compare the code generated when I add block in the Admin panel: https://prnt.sc/SO0v5SXMKQqD . Also I'm not sure why md5() function we are using and both examples have different values.